# x86: Patch on execution opcode in an exe file, but getting memory could not be written when debugging on IDA

Tags: memory, permissions, x86, paging, ida

I'm trying to add an hook for some function in my exe file, which should write a byte to the memory being executed after the hook finish (inside the function himself).

In order to do it, I patched the first opcode of the function there to be jmp command to a section which I patched to be the single opcode
[image]

where byte_401501 is byte in the original function (which I hooked) and I want to change it to be 0x40.

Unfortunately, I get this error on IDA when running the exe after the patch...
[image]
I believe that it's a problem with the permission, and maybe the code under the function is consider to be executable only. I could have just changed this single byte using patch in IDA, but I wish to do it within my hook, and on execution.

Does someone here know how to change the permission of the specific address to be writeable? Or how can I get rid of this error?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Even after changing my segment on IDA to be writeable, I don't succeed to run this code..